# Does the Higgs Boson "operate" inside, outside, or throughout the volume of an Atom?

Tags: higgs

Is the Higgs force *exchanged* by particles within the atomic structure, or is the Higgs force exerted on individual particles, at the quantum scale, independent of their atomic coorelations?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to ask if the Higgs acts on individual subatomic particles or on the atoms as a whole?

Answer (score 4):

The Higgs interaction is an interaction between quantum fields not between particles. To take electrons as an example: it is as a result of the interaction between the Higgs field and the electron field that the excitations of the electron field, i.e. electrons, have mass. So all electrons will have the same mass because they are all excitations of the same quantum field that interacts with the Higgs field. The electron mass doesn't depend on whether the electrons are in atoms or not.

Incidentally, the Higgs boson you mention in the title is an excitation of the Higgs field, but it's not the mechanism by which particles gain mass.

Comment: So particles have intrinsic mass. Which I understand to be a limitation of degrees of freedom...yes?

Comment: The best reasonably accessible explanation I've seen is [this article on Matt Strassler's blog](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/how-the-higgs-field-works-with-math/1-the-basic-idea/). It's not a trivial subject, and you will need to rev up the brain cells to get through it, but I'd say it's worth giving it a try.